# Geodesic traingle is contained within the $3\delta$ ball centered at any of its vertex

Tags: geodesic, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

Given any vertex of a geodesic triangle in hyperbolic space, show that the entire triangle is contained in the $3\delta$ ball centred at that vertex, where $\delta$ is the constant of hyperbolicity.

Now since it's a geodesic triangle in hyperbolic space then the vertex $x$ is at most $\delta$ away from one of the sides, let that point on the side be $p$. Therefore $d(x,p)=\delta$.

Not sure how to do next

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear right now. Do you mean: "Given any vertex of a geodesic triangle in a hyperbolic space, show that the entire triangle is contained in the $3\delta$ ball centered at that vertex, where $\delta$ is the constant of hyperbolicity"?

Comment: Yes thanks for your clarity will update the question text

Comment: You should still include the things you have tried for this problem so far though.

Comment: Thanks I showed my thought above though not sure what to do next

Comment: What makes you think that this is true? Did you look at examples such as trees?

Comment: Not really, my knowledge in geometric group theory is very narrow. However, I thought it is this way from the definition of geodesic triangles in hyperbolic space. That given one edge it will be contained within the open ball of radius $\delta$ constructed from the points in the other two edges.

Comment: Then, as I said, consider the case of $0$-hyperbolic spaces (trees). If this is too hard, consider the case when your space is the real line with the standard metric.